# expandableListView children with text and image

Tags: java, android

I have an expandableListView where each group has two children. The child rows are for editing or deleting the group. How do I insert images for the child rows?

```
Group 1
   <image here> Edit            <-- child 1
   <image here> Delete          <-- child 2
```

I use a SimpleExpandableListAdapter

Hope someone can help :)

Answer (score 0):

You should define a layout for your child, and then specify it when you create your ListAdapter. You could do something like this, although using RelativeLayout would be much better (I used LinearLayout because it's a bit easier to understand):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="vertical">
       <LinearLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal">
            <ImageView android:id="@+id/edit_icon" android:padding="2dip" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/edit"/> 
            <TextView android:id="@+id/edit_label" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textSize="40sp" android:text="Edit"/> 
       </LinearLayout>
       <LinearLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal">
            <ImageView android:id="@+id/delete_icon" android:padding="2dip" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/delete"/> 
            <TextView android:id="@+id/delete_label" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textSize="40sp" android:text="Delete"/>
        </LinearLayout> 
</LinearLayout>
```

Then you specify this layout when you call setListAdapter().

Comment: But by using your layout each child will get both a delete + edit image and delete + edit text? I want the first child to have the edit image and text and then the next child to have the delete image and text?

Comment: Yes, that's what the above does -- I didn't understand what you wanted. If you want a list with just two child items, you can inflate two children in the list separately. I recommend taking a look at the book available from http://commonsware.com/: you can get an older version for free, which is all you need for something like this.

Comment: Where can you get a free older version of one of the books?

Comment: Click on a book name, scroll to the bottom, and then on the "Four-to-Free Guarantee". The newest covers Android 2.1 SDK: http://commonsware.com/Android/Android-3_0-CC.pdf -- I purchased a subscription, and it's definitely worth it.